# Why isn't this mysqli query fetching?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why isn't this table fetching? I've been pulling my eyes out for over an hour on this one query. I'm going insane.

I've tested the query in phpmyadmin and it is working...

```
$query = "
SELECT e.earning_link_id, COUNT(e.earning_id) AS visits, ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, now(), l.link_created)) AS age, l.link_link, o.owner_id
FROM earnings AS e
INNER JOIN links AS l
ON e.earning_link_id = l.link_id
LEFT JOIN owners as o
ON l.link_id = o.owner_link_id
WHERE o.owner_id > 0
GROUP BY earning_link_id
ORDER BY COUNT(e.earning_id) / ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, now(), l.link_created)) DESC
LIMIT 10
";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();
        $statement->bind_result($link_id, $link_visit_count, $link_age, $link_link, $link_owner_id);

        echo '<table>';
        while ($statement->fetch())
        {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><i class="fa fa-link"></i> '.$link_link.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';

    $statement->free_result();
    $statement->close();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Does your `if` true?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the problem. It's the query after all. Phpmyadmin keeps OLD RESULTS TABLE UP even if you return zero results.....so I was looking at OLD RESULTS.....*screams in high pitch*

Answer (score 1):

Try remove ->store_result();

```
<?php   
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $query = " SELECT 1 as id, 2 AS visits, 3 AS age, 4 as link_link,5 as owner_id  ";
    if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
    {
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->bind_result($link_id, $link_visit_count, $link_age, $link_link, $link_owner_id);

            echo '<table>';
            while ($statement->fetch())
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-link"></i> '.$link_id.'</td>';
                    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-link"></i> '.$link_visit_count.'</td>';
                    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-link"></i> '.$link_age.'</td>';
                    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-link"></i> '.$link_link.'</td>';
                    echo '<td><i class="fa fa-link"></i> '.$link_owner_id.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';

        $statement->close();
    }

    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

This work it , test it and change for your  query